# Refreshing Windows 8.1 While Dual-booting Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, 15.10

Currently, I'm dual-booting my Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 15.10

For your information, both of this operating systems are installed on separate partition.

At this moment, I'm planning to refresh/reset my sluggish Windows 8.1. So my question is, will such action wipe my grub loader which may not allow me to access my Ubuntu or the grub loader will still remain intact?

I have googled previously but the situation was mentioning both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu were installed on the same partition. But what about my case then?

Comment: Do you mean separate hard disks or separate partitions?

Comment: separate partition.

Comment: In that case Eduardo's answer below will work for you. Talaat's answer is the easier one but tends to add unnecessary stuff to the EFI partition.

Answer (score 1):

Reset Windows 8.1 normally, but BEFORE, make sure you have an Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB, so if anything happens to GRUB, you can simply boot from the Live media, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Replacing 'X' with the correct partition number for your Ubuntu installation.